# Returning SQL data within an image tag using PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

When I run the following file I get the database data i.e it prints it out on the website so I know my connections are good.

```
<html>
<?php include 'config.php'?>
<?php include 'header.php'?>

<?php 
$sql = "SELECT name, image FROM images";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo $row["name"], $row["image"];
}
?>

</div>
</html>
```

However when I try and format the results like below

```
<html>
<?php include 'config.php'?>
<?php include 'header.php'?>

<?php 
$sql = "SELECT name, image FROM images";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo <div id = "bookbar">
<img src= "$row['image']" alt = "image">
<p> $row['name'] </p>

</div>
}
?>

</div>
</html>
```

it doesn't work. Can anyone help me fix the code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? THe wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this your code didn't close/open the php tags properly also don't echo like that

```
<?php include 'config.php'?>
<?php include 'header.php'?>

<?php 

$sql = "SELECT name, image FROM images";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       ?>

       <div id = "bookbar">
            <img src= "<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt = "image">
            <p><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p>
        </div>

       <?php
    }
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

If you want to echo something out

Its better to close on open the php tags like so

```
PHP goes here
?>
HTML goes here
<?php
PHP goes here
```

And if you want to echo something inside the HTML just do this

```
<span> <?php echo "something" ?> </span>
```

much easier and makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

change your echo statement to -

```
echo '<div id = "bookbar"><img src= "' . $row['image'] . '" alt = "image"><p>'. $row['name'] .'</p>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a syntax problem - you can't use `echo` like that, it has to echo a string variable. You should be seeing an error message about it.

You *could* keep the echo statement and put all the HTML inside a string, and concatenate (or interpolate) the PHP data into it. But IMO the easiest thing here in terms of readability and maintenance is to step out of the PHP tags, print the HTML, embed some PHP tags in it for the variables, and then step back in again to continue with the code. It makes the HTML far easier to understand:

```
?>
<div id="bookbar">
  <img src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="image">
  <p><?php echo $row['name'] ?></p>
</div>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are in `php` mode you should `echo` strings as php variables wrapped with single quotes:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo '<div id = "bookbar">';
    echo '<img src="' . $row['image'] . '" alt = "image">';
    echo '<p>' . $row['name'] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```